# Is a D Type Edge triggered Master Slave flip flop considered a 1bit memory cell?

Tags: memory, flipflop

So in class we talked about how a D-type edge triggered flip flop is considered a 1bit memory cell. I think this is the same for a D-type latch.

My question is, since a D-type edge triggered master slave flip flop uses 2 D-latches, is it considered a 1bit memory cell or 2bits since it has 2 D-latches? And if it is, if I wanted to theoretically create a 1MB memory module entirely out of master slave flip flops, would I just take 1MB and divide by 2 bits(or however many bits the flip flop has)?

Comment: And multiply by 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, technically, a master-slave flip-flop counts as 2 bits of memory. However, because of the way they're connected, you can't really store (and then retrieve) two independent bits of information in them.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Although it contains two latches, functionally it is only usable as a one-bit memory cell.

Comment: @EricSmith: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I disagree with "technically ... counts as 2 bits of memory". I have never seen a master-slave accounted for as 2 bits of memory. The fact that it contains two latches doesn't IMO make it 2 bits of memory in any sense, technical or otherwise.

Comment: @EricSmith: Do you understand how a master-slave FF goes through four internal states in the course of its operation? The only way this can happen is if it has two binary state variables. So it does have two bits of memory, but you can't store two *independent* bits of information in them. That's what I meant by "technically".

Comment: I understand the operation of master-slave flip-flops quite well.  Having four internal states doesn't give it the property of storing two bits of memory in any useful sense.  I can design a circuit with 137 internal states that serves as zero bits of memory.

Comment: Here's a puzzle for you. I think we can both agree that half of an SN74LS74 dual edge-triggered D flip flop is _effectively_ one bit of usable memory. There's a logic diagram of the internals in the TI datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54s74.pdf But by your definition, how many bits of "memory" does half of an SN74LS74 "technically" contain?

Comment: @EricSmith: The logic that TI (and others) actually uses to implement the '74 is not the dual latch structure that the OP described, and that my answer is addressing. If you think you have a better answer, by all means, post it!

Comment: I know that the 7474 doesn't use the master-slave design; that was in fact my point. I'm using it as an example of how your "technically... two bits of memory" completely falls apart when you try to use the same reasoning on a different FF circuit. So if you're sticking to the claim that a master-slave FF is "technically.... two bits of memory", then I'd like to know how many bits of memory "technically" you think half of a 7474 is.

Answer (score 0):

A cascaded sequence of D-latches which uses N clock phases will require N latches for every N-1 bits.  A flip flop uses two D-latches will thus need two latches to store one bit.  On the other hand, a sequence of 20 D-latches which were triggered on four different phases in a suitably-rotating rotating pattern would be able to hold 16 bits.  I haven't seen such a pattern used very often, but it could relatively easily yield a significant space savings.